# Como posso fazer uma cópia de várias tabelas em uma nova tabela usando SQL SERVER?

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server

Tenho várias tabelas com os mesmos número de colunas. e quero inserir os registros dessas tabelas em uma nova tabela. Alguém tem uma ideia? pois só consegui inserir uma e não aceita o resto de tabelas que tenho.

```
select  *
from DATATRAN2013_CSV A 
UNION
 select  * from DATATRAN2014_CSV B 
 UNION
select *from  DATATRAN2015_CSV C 
UNION
select * from DATATRAN2016_CSV D
```

Comment: Isso é um Insert com sub consulta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode inserir usando o modelo abaixo:

```
INSERT INTO tabelan(coluna1, coluna2, coluna3, coluna4, colunaz)
SELECT coluna1, coluna2, coluna3, coluna4, colunaz FROM tabela1
UNION
SELECT coluna1, coluna2, coluna3, coluna4, colunaz FROM tabela2
UNION
SELECT coluna1, coluna2, coluna3, coluna4, colunaz FROM tabela3
UNION
SELECT coluna1, coluna2, coluna3, coluna4, colunaz FROM tabelaz
```

É interessante nomear as colunas para não errar na ordem do `INSERT`.

Importante ressaltar que o `UNION` irá eliminar linhas repetidas, então caso queira manter registros duplicados entre tabelas diferentes, utilize o `UNION ALL`.

Comment: UNION descarta linhas repetidas (se houver).

Comment: @JoséDiz isso invalida a resposta a ponto de receber um `downvote`? É interessante dar uma lida nos privilégios quando os adquire, como por exemplo [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) para utilizar o fórum de maneira correta.

Comment: @Sorack valeu amigo ajudou bastante

Answer (score 4):

Utilizando o `Union`, as colunas tem de ter o mesmo nome e estar na mesma ordem.

Obs: Neste caso não estará copiando, apenas juntando o resultado da seleção de várias tabelas. Para copiar para um outra tabela precisa fazer um `insert` com o resultado destes `Unions`

Comment: valeu amigo pela dica percebi isso quando eu estava tentar me matar ontem inserido isso.

Answer (score 0):

As sugestões desta resposta consideram que uma nova tabela deve ser criada e que as tabelas de origem estão declaradas com colunas na mesma sequência.

**(1)** É possível inserir uma tabela de cada vez, sem necessidade de UNION ALL:

```
-- código #1
SELECT coluna_1, coluna_2, ..., coluna_n 
   into DATATRAN_CSV
   from DATATRAN2013_CSV;

INSERT into DATATRAN_CSV (coluna_1, coluna_2, ..., coluna_n)
  SELECT coluna_1, coluna_2, ..., coluna_n 
     from DATATRAN2014_CSV;

INSERT into DATATRAN_CSV (coluna_1, coluna_2, ..., coluna_n)
  SELECT coluna_1, coluna_2, ..., coluna_n 
     from DATATRAN2015_CSV;

INSERT into DATATRAN_CSV (coluna_1, coluna_2, ..., coluna_n)
  SELECT coluna_1, coluna_2, ..., coluna_n 
     from DATATRAN2016_CSV;
```

Desta forma utiliza-se menos recursos de memória.

---

**(2)** Caso queira realizar a junção das tabelas de origem, antes de criar a nova tabela, eis outra opção:

```
-- código #2
with cteDATATRAN as (
SELECT * from DATATRAN2013_CSV
union all
SELECT * from DATATRAN2014_CSV
union all
SELECT * from DATATRAN2015_CSV
union all
SELECT * from DATATRAN2016_CSV
)
SELECT * 
  into DATATRAN_CSV 
  from cteDATATRAN;
```

Observe que deve utilizar o UNION ALL para obter a união completa. Se utilizar somente UNION, além do processo ficar mais lento, as linhas repetidas serão descartadas.

---

**(3)** Para ter controle absoluto, sugiro que não utilize * na lista de colunas das tabelas de origem mas sim que defina o nome das colunas:

```
-- código #3
with cteDATATRAN as (
SELECT coluna_1, coluna_2, ..., coluna_n 
  from DATATRAN2013_CSV

union all
SELECT coluna_1, coluna_2, ..., coluna_n 
  from DATATRAN2014_CSV

union all
SELECT coluna_1, coluna_2, ..., coluna_n 
  from DATATRAN2015_CSV

union all
SELECT coluna_1, coluna_2, ..., coluna_n 
  from DATATRAN2016_CSV
)
SELECT * 
  into DATATRAN_CSV 
  from cteDATATRAN;
```

---